# Gitlab behind NAT on an alternative port?

Tags: sockets, ubuntu, nginx, gitlab, nat

This is a fresh install on Ubuntu 16.04.

I have been able to change the port and edit the "/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb" file.

*changes;*

```
external_url 'http://superawesomedomain.com:2345'
nginx['listen_port'] = 2345
nginx['proxy_set_headers'] = {
 "Host" => "$http_host",
 "X-Real-IP" => "$remote_addr",
 "X-Forwarded-For" => "$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for",
 "X-Forwarded-Proto" => "https",
 "X-Forwarded-Ssl" => "on"
}
```

When I try to access Gitlab from the browser, I get a **502** error "Whoops, GitLab is taking too much time to respond."

And this in the logs:

> ==> /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_error.log <== 2016/05/04 00:43:53 [error] 1599#0: *14 connect() to
>   unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/socket failed (111: Connection
>   refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server:
>   superawesomedomain.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "http://unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/socket:/favicon.ico",
>   host: "superawesomedomain.com:2345", referrer:
>   "http://superawesomedomain.com:2345/"

The only ports configured behind NAT to work on this machine are; 2345 and 8080.

What am I missing? Ultimately I would prefer that it be http**s**://superawesomedomain.com:2345/

Comment: This question is off topic for stackoverflow.    it should be posted on superuser or serverfault.stackexchange.com as it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working by using the IP of the server instead of the URL in the config:

```
external_url 'http://192.168.0.20:2345'
```

After doing that, GitLab was accessible from the //superawesomedomain.com:2345/ address. I am not sure why this worked, but it seems this is the only way to get it working with NAT and forwarded ports.